# Алгоритм изменения масштаба

Tags: алгоритм, масштабирование, processing

Как сделать так, чтобы центр приближения был по центру

Переменная zoom отвечает за приближение

```
void drawAxis()
{
 stroke(0, 0, 255);
 line(moveX*zoom, (moveY+50000*zoom)*zoom, moveX*zoom, (moveY-50000*zoom)*zoom);
 stroke(255, 0, 0);
 line((moveX+50000*zoom)*zoom, moveY*zoom, (moveX-50000*zoom)*zoom, moveY*zoom);
}
void drawGraph()
{
 for (y=-500; y<500; y+=0.1)
 {
   x=func(y);
   line( (y*10+moveX)*zoom, (x*10+moveY)*zoom, (yprev*10+moveX)*zoom, (xprev*10+moveY)*zoom);
   xprev=x;
   yprev=y;
 }
}
void draw()
{
 background(0);
 stroke(255);
 //вывод переменных
 varDraw();
 //сохраняем значения с предыдущего кадра
 xprev=x;
 yprev=y;
 //рисуем график+оси xy
 drawGraph();
 drawAxis();
 //костыль для плавного зума
 zoom=(zoom+zoom+zoom+zoom+zoomTar)/5;
 //mousePressed() не работает так как мне хотелось
 if(mousePressed==true)
 {
 moveX+=(mouseX-pmouseX)/zoom;
 moveY+=(mouseY-pmouseY)/zoom;
 }
}
```

Переменные

```
float xprev=0, yprev=0;
float zoom=0.0001, zoomTar=0.75, zoomTmp=1;//zoomTar - число к которому стремится переменная zoom
float moveX=500, moveY=500;
float x=0, y=0;
```

Полный код:[Тык](https://pastebin.com/LHD89vtQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно отнимать от всех координат координаты центра, умножать на зум, потом прибавлять координаты центра, примерно так:

```
zoomedX = ScreenWidth/2 + (X - ScreenWidth/2) * zoom
```